# Why doesn't colon work in VintageEx?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm new to Sublime Text and am using the latest beta version Build 3047.

I installed VintageEx via Package Control, and also enabled Vintage. However, the command-line mode cannot be triggered after pressing the `:` key. I suspect it might be the key binding issue, but I've no idea of what to do with it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Sublime Text 3 compatible packages: https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/wiki/Sublime-Text-3-Compatible-Packages

Try using Vintageous instead of VintageEx.

Comment: Vintageous colon (:) doesn't work for me in Sublime Text v3.1.1